# SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED error displayed while connecting to SignalR through Python

Tags: signalr

from requests import Session
from signalr import Connection
with Session() as session:

```
connection = Connection("https://localhost:443/Platform", session)

Signalhub = connection.register_hub('MessageRouteHubspot')
```

**with connection:**

```
    Signalhub.server.invoke('subscribe','1_FPGA_ACCESS_COMMANDS')
```

When executing this I'm getting error requests.exceptions.

> SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:590)

How to bypass/ignore SSL verification??

Answer (score 0):

Python's `signalr-client` uses WebSocket package to establish the connection. WebSocket package is then using OpenSSL to do SSL/TLS. It appears that the WebSocket client requires client CA (Certificate Authority) bundle to be passed as the environment variable `WEBSOCKET_CLIENT_CA_BUNDLE`.

Exporting this variable with the CA bundle including the certificates signing the original site's certificate should do the trick. Below is an example on my Ubuntu based system.

```
$ export WEBSOCKET_CLIENT_CA_BUNDLE=/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
$ python test-signalr.py
```